# PHP OOP: How can I access static field and object?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I want to call getAllPersons() in another class, but I receive an error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare non static Core\Model::$db as static Models\Person::$db

```
class Person extends Model {
    protected static $db;
    protected static $table = 'person';


    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct ();
        self::$db = Database::get ();
    }


    public static function getAllPersons() {
        return self::$db->select ( "SELECT personID, firstname, lastname FROM " . PREFIX . self::$table );
        // $db->select is not static
    }
}
```

Another.php:

```
$data ['persons'] = Person::getPersons ();
```

Comment: You extend Model and it declares `$db` as non-static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `self::$db` (for example in your getAllPersons function) always refers to the $db which was declared at the Person class (which is not defined). 
Try the following in your code (change self:: to static::):

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct ();
        static::$db = Database::get (); 
    }
```

The previous will allow the constructor to initialize your $db var once you initialize an object of your class.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you all you need to know. In your `Model` class, you have a variable `$db` that is declared as a normal property, not a static one. When you try to declare another `$db` variable, but change it to being static, PHP throws the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You can not extend non static (public) properties or methods of *Parent* class AS static and *vise versa*.
You have to apply the same *access modifiers* as in Parent class OR rename properties(methods) in your *Child* class